# How to parse has_many association before_save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am trying to achieve ability to pass array of strings to `has_many` association, so that I can iterate over them and create association instance.

I have simple structure `Task <-> TaskTag <-> Tag`

Both `Task` and `Tag` has one field: `title`

I'm willing to achieve ability to update with such call:

```
@task.update({:title=>"Updated Task Title", :tags=>["NewTag", "ExistingTag"]})
```

so that it creates and sets tag with title "NewTag" and sets "ExistingTag"

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :tags

  before_save :set_tags, if: -> { self.tags.present? }

  has_many :task_tags
  has_many :tags, through: :task_tags
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags


  private
    def set_tags
      tag_instances = self.tags.map do |tag|
        if tag.is_a?(String)
          Tag.where(title: tag).first_or_create
        else
          tag
        end
      end

      self.tags = tag_instances
    end
end
```

I have achieved that it creates instance if it doesn't exist, but it does not create `TaskTag` instance

Comment: You can't have both an `attr_accessor :tags` and a `has_many :tags`. They both provide accessor methods and the last one will win.

Comment: @meagar makes sense, you have any idea though on how to achieve my goal?

Comment: Ofcourse it doesn't create `TaskTag` instance as you didn't say so. `first_or_create` accepts a block. You can create `TaskTag` instance inside the block.

Answer (score 1):

> I have achieved that it creates instance if it doesn't exist, but it
>   does not create TaskTag instance

Normally in `has_many,<> :through` association, when `collection_singular_ids`(i.e, `tag_ids` or `task_ids` in your case) are present in the `params`, Rails upon create, will also create **new entries** in the **joined table**(i.e, `task_tags` in your case) with `f_key` values as those values of `collection_singular_ids`(`tag_id = tag_ids`) and the ***id of current instance***(`task_id = @task.id`).

Your situation is different as you have `tags` instead of `tag_ids`. You should create instances for `TaskTag` like so

```
def set_tags
  tag_instances = self.tags.map do |tag|
    if tag.is_a?(String)
      Tag.where(title: tag).first_or_create do |t|
        t.task_tags.create(task_id: self.id) # This will create new entries for task_tags with tag_id as t.id and task_id as self.id
      end
    else
      tag
    end
  end
  self.tags = tag_instances
end
```